# sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject vs org.mozilla.javascript.NativeObject

Tags: rhino, nashorn

I am really stuck at this now..

Essentially I have a Java Map, which I would like to pass it to a Javascript Code, so that in my JS code I can use dot notation to refer the keys in this Map. ( I know I can serialize the map into JSON and deserialize it back and pass it into JS, but I don't like that ) I have this piece of the unit code

```
@Test
public void mapToJsTest() throws Exception{
    Map m = Maps.newHashMap();
    m.put("name", "john");

    NativeObject nobj = new NativeObject();
    for (Object k : m.keySet()) {
        nobj.defineProperty((String)k, m.get(k), NativeObject.READONLY);
    }

    engine.eval("function test(obj){ return obj.name;}");
    Object obj = ((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction("test", nobj);

    Assert.assertEquals(obj, "john");
}
```

If I am using 
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeObject 
then the test won't pass,

However, if I am using 
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject
then the test will pass.

However, we all know that we shouldn't rely on these internal classes, and when I deploy my code on the server side, trying to access
this internal class will cause other problems.

So how do I achieve this with just "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeObject"?

BTW, I am using Rhino

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

For Nashorn, it is much easier, I can pass Map directly into JS code.

Comment: You probably have to use the `engine` from your Rhino jar file as well if you want to use engine-specific interfaces.

Comment: @Thilo I am not following, can you paste a little code ?

Comment: If you load it via `ScriptEngineManager` you will get the version in the JDK (`sun.org.mozilla`). If you want to use Rhino from your JAR file, load it with the native Rhino API instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11080622/14955

Comment: This may also work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872885/14955  Then you can request `getEngineByName("rhino17R5")`.

Comment: @Thino thank you so much, this thread works perfect stackoverflow.com/a/28872885/14955

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're stuck with older JDK (jdk7 or below) for some reason, I'd recommend moving to jdk8u. You've ES 5.1 compliant JS implementation (Nashorn) that is bundled with JDK8+.

Comment: If I can move over, then I won't need to ask here.